# Pie chart legend styling using Chart js

Tags: label, chart.js, legend, pie-chart, styling

How to style legend type from rectangle box to circle?
pie chart using chartjs.org[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish so, by setting `usePointStyle` property to `true` for legend labels in your chart options, like this ...

```
options: {
   legend: {
      labels: {
         usePointStyle: true  //<-- set this
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the dataset like this:

```
datasets: [{
    data: [10, 20, 30],
    backgroundColor: [
       'red',
       'orange',
       'blue'
    ],
}]
```